# Search input react

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

I want to make a search in my list of pokemons, but I don't know how.
I tried some methods but don't work.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import loading from "../layout/images/loading.gif";

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=21&offset=0",
    pokemon: null,
    buttonsPage: true,
  };

  // Information about pokemon
  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
  }

  // function for loading all pokemons into list of pokemons, also hiding buttons next and previous
  async allData() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=2000&offset=0"
    );
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
    this.state.buttonsPage = false;
    console.log(this.state.buttonsPage);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  // function for showing a list of pokemons with pagination, also showing buttons next and previous
  async pageView() {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=21&offset=0"
    );
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
    this.state.buttonsPage = true;
    console.log(this.state.buttonsPage);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  // function for next page
  async nextPage() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ url: res.data.next });
    const res2 = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res2.data["results"] });
  }

  //function for previous page
  async previousPage() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    console.log(res.data.previous);
    if (res.data.previous) {
      this.setState({ url: res.data.previous });
      const res2 = await axios.get(this.state.url);
      this.setState({ pokemon: res2.data["results"] });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=21&offset=0",
      });
    }
  }

  

  render() {
   return (
      <>
      {/* buttons for listing all pokemons or going back to page view */}
        <button
          onClick={() => this.allData()}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary mt-2 ml-2 mb-2"
          style={{ display: this.state.buttonsPage ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          All pokemons
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.pageView()}
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary mt-2 ml-2 mb-2"
          style={{ display: this.state.buttonsPage ? "none" : "block" }}
        >
          Back to page view
        </button>
        {/* Listing all pokemons, or if pokemons are not loaded showing loading gif */}
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.pokemon.map((pokemon) => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                pokemonName={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <img
            src={loading}
            style={{ width: "15em", height: "15em" }}
            className="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2"
          />
        )}
        {/* Buttons for next and previous page */}
        <div
          className="container-fluid mx-auto"
          style={{ display: this.state.buttonsPage ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          <button
            onClick={() => this.previousPage()}
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-secondary mt-4 ml-2 mb-2"
          >
            Previous page
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => this.nextPage()}
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-secondary mt-4 ml-2 mb-2 float-right"
          >
            Next page
          </button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone explain me how to do this?

I have some idea, I need to filter Names of pokemons by input letters and then push that in my pokemon array (setState) and my list will update, and that looks like easy task, but in reality it's not for me.

So, any solution and explanation will extremely be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a input to search, on handleChange function; you setState your search value:

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.searchValue} 
 onChange={this.handleChange} 
/>
```

then before render you filter your pokemons:

```
const tempPokemonList =
        this.state.searchValue && this.state.pokemon && 
        this.state.pokemon.length > 0
            ? this.state.pokemon.filter(pokemon => {
                    return pokemon.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase());
              })
            : this.state.pokemon;
```

and then you map your filtered tempPokemonList in your div.